# how to import data in orange hrm 2.7.1?

Tags: php, orangehrm

I want to just trnasfer the data from orange hrm 2.6.3 to 2.7.1.

I found export data functionality of the employees from Admin -> Data Import/Export

And I found that the data are imported in 2.7.1 from PIM -> configuration -> data import/export but in the sample csv i found that there are lots of columns like its all the account details,nationality,country which are not the field in the exported csv.

Or is there any other way to transfer the data from 2.6.3 to 2.7.1 using system or direct from database.

Please suggest me if anyone has any idea.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is the instruction.

1. in your old PC, go to localhost/xampp.
2. then go to phpmyadmin section.
3. and click on Export DataBase, and export your DataBase and save the file in your computer.
4. go to new pc and access the localhost/xampp.
5. then go to phpmyadmin section and import your database.
6. Finish

Answer (score 0):

This is the "backend" way. I don't have any special method for OrangeHRM data migration, so I just use the usual database dump.
Basically, I'll dump the database/table first. Then, I'll drop the current database/table (make sure to do a backup copy) before importing a new one.

If you are importing a database, try to use the same name as the old one or else you might need to delete the `symfony/cache/orangehrm` folder,the `lib/confs/Conf.php` and the `symfony/config/databases.yml` file and start a new installation. OrangeHRM uses YAML library for data serialization.

Not sure if there are a lot of differences in terms of db structure between these two versions.